# Trying to run Scala test, getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have a Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2. Everytime I run the Scala tests in the project, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
    ... 5 more
```

I checked the versions of the dependencies and I have added the Scala SDK to the project module as well. I also added the Scala plugin to the Gradle file and installed the Scala plugin in IntelliJ IDEA. Also, the tests run without an error on my colleague's computer so we have no idea what the error could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause: I have an accentuated letter in my user directory's name and IDEA is always trying to use some file from AppData under that directory. I have already changed the `idea.properties` file, but it has no effect regarding that file.

A possible workaround is using gradle (or maven/sbt/etc.). In my case, I use gradle, I just add `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` to the scala class I want to test, then execute gradle's test task.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution of command line length limitation was crucial. Idea offers about 3 ways of how to overcome too long command. Choose another and check.

It's in run configurations.